# setting up a http basic authorization password for aws ec2 load balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, basic-authentication, amazon-ecs, amazon-elb

I have an ECS cluster with a private IP address that corresponds to the target IP address of EC2 Load Balancing Target Group that corresponds to a specific Load Balancer. When an HTTP request is made to this load balancer I'd like it to present a prompt for HTTP Basic Authorization credentials. How might I do this? Is it even possible?

I'd also like to put some restrictions on the path as well.

```
<If "req('Host') =~ /mywebsite.com$/ && %{REQUEST_URI} !~ /agreement/">
        Include /etc/apache2/conf-available/htpasswd.conf
</If>
```

Is this possible?

In the Load Balancer management page I can add and edit listeners. If the listener is using HTTPS I can add a rule that has an "Authenticate..." action but the two options available to me are Amazon Cognito and OIDC, neither of which seem to do HTTP Basic Authorization. I guess AWS Lambda lets you create Lambda based authorizers instead of having to use Amazon Cognito per https://www.cloudmailin.com/blog/basic_auth_with_aws_lambda but it doesn't look like you can use Lambda's with Load Balancers on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set up Lambda to receive requests from an Application Load Balancers. See [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-alb.html) for more info on that.